# Cocos2d-x, Xcode4 Build Errors in NSObjCRuntime.h

Tags: iphone, xcode4, objective-c++, cocos2d-x, build-error

I had been working on a cocos2d-x project for the QNX platform and I am now moving to the iPhone platform to finish developing.  I copied all the files over and created a new Xcode4 project and then imported them, but when I go to compile it, I get 40-something errors in the NSObjCRuntime.h.
Then it says: Too many errors emitted, stopping now.
Some of the errors read:
Unknown type name 'NSString'; did you mean 'CCString'?
Use of undeclared identifier 'NSString'; did you mean 'CCString'?
Use of undeclared identifier 'Protocol'
Use of undeclared identifier 'format'; did you mean 'normal'?
Use of undeclared identifier 'namestr'

I looked at my Prefix.pch file, after research this seemed to be part of the problem, but everything is wrapped in the #ifdef **OBJC** ... #endif condition so I don't think that's the issue.  I even tried commenting out the code there and still it gave me the same errors.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

EDIT: This actually seems to be a problem with the OpenGLES library.  When it's not included and I comment out all gl calls, the errors go away.  Any thoughts?
I used this code to load the OpenGLES Library:

```
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!  It was because in Cocos2d-x 2.0 they've changed a lot of the drawing functions from version 1.  It's no longer like regular OpenGLES, you have to use their built in methods to set up OpenGLES.

See this link: [Migrate to v2.0](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3amigrate_to_v2.0#internals)